# Make "git pull" ask for confirmation when pulling different branch

Tags: linux, git

When working with many projects and branches at the same time, I occasionally do stupid mistake like pulling into the wrong branch. For example being on branch `master` I did `git pull origin dangerous_code` and didn't notice that for quite some time. This small mistake caused a lot of mess.

Is there any way to make git ask for confirmation when I attempt to pull a branch other than branch that is currently checked out? Basically I want it to ask for confirmation if the branch name doesn't match (checked out and the one being pulled).

Comment: *Is there any way to make git ask for confirmation when I attempt to pull a branch other than branch that is currently checked out?* Unfortunately, a remote branch may have a different name from that of the local branch that tracks it. What you could do, though, is check whether the upstream (if any) of the current branch corresponds to the branch you're trying to pull. Would that work for you?

Comment: *Unfortunately, a remote branch may have a different name from that of the local branch that tracks it* OK, but isn't that rather uncommon? At least this never happens in the environments that I work in.

Comment: *Ok, but isn't that rather uncommon?* Not at all: `git push -u origin  master:jubobs` will set the upstream of `master` to `origin/jubobs`. I'm mentioning this here because a robust solution to your problem should cover this case. You may want to reformulate your question in light of this information.

Comment: Nevertheless, it still not my case. For sake of simplicity, let's focus on checking branch names only, ok?

Answer (score 5):

For now, I'll focus on how to prompt the user for confirmation before *any* pull is carried out.

Unfortunately, because there is no such thing as a pre-pull [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.html), I don't think you can get the actual `pull` command to directly do that for you. As I see it, you have two options:

### 1 - Use `fetch` then `merge` (instead of `pull`)

Instead of running `git pull`, run `git fetch`, then `git merge` or `git rebase`; breaking down `pull` into the two steps it naturally consists of will force you to double-check what you're about to merge/rebase into what.

### 2 - Define an alias that asks for confirmation before a pull

Define and use a `pull` wrapper (as a Git alias) that prompts you for confirmation if you attempt to pull from a remote branch whose name is different from the current local branch.

Write the following lines to a script file called `git-cpull.sh` (for *confirm, then pull*) in `~/bin/`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-cpull.sh

if [ "$2" != "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)" ]
then
    while true; do
        read -p "Are you sure about this pull?" yn
        case "$yn" in
            [Yy]*)
                git pull $@;
                break
                ;;
            [Nn]*)
                exit
                ;;
            *)
                printf %s\\n "Please answer yes or no."
        esac
    done
else
    git pull $@
fi
```

Then define the alias:

```sh
git config --global alias.cpull '!sh git-cpull.sh'
```

After that, if, for example, you run

```sh
git cpull origin master
```

but the current branch is *not* `master`, you'll be asked for confirmation before any `pull` is actually carried out.

#### Example

```sh
$ git branch
* master
$ git cpull origin foobar
Are you sure about this pull?n
$ git cpull origin master
From https://github.com/git/git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Actually second option is perfectly fine for me

Comment: _Is there any way to make Git ask for confirmation when I attempt to pull a branch other than the remote branch tracked by the local branch currently checked out_
**Yes** :) Basically I want it to ask for confirmation if the branch name doesn't match (checked out and the one being pulled). That's all I need.

Comment: This is not an the answer to my question. But what I think that could work is to call `git status` or `git branch |grep "*"` in your script to see what is the current branch and match that with the branch from the command line.