# How can I get git push to ask for confirmation or run some checks?

Tags: git, git-push

I would like to customize my Git prompt in such a way that it reminds me or runs checks for me before I push something to a remote repo.

For instance, when I run

```
git push
```

Git should ask the user

```
Did you run unit tests locally?
```

or something to that effect, so that I don't accidentally push code that is not unit-tested.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565460/make-git-pull-ask-for-confirmation-when-pulling-different-branch

Comment: “git should prompt me” - The problem is that you will quickly develop the habit of typing "y" immediately after typing "git push", and the prompt won't do any good. Better: "git commit" and "git merge" set a flag that **prevents** "git push" from working, and running your tests clears the flag.

Comment: Git's `pre-push` hook seems appropriate, here...

Comment: @Jubobs, git's pre-push hook only executes after the remote refs have been updated, which will result in a delay before the prompt.

Comment: @mrkiffie A minor inconvenience, IMO. Using the `pre-push` hook, especially for running checks (rather than merely asking for confirmation) would be cleaner than defining an ad-hoc wrapper for `git push`.

Comment: @Jubobs, I also prefer running tests on a `pre-commit` hook. But as the OP asked about before pushing, a `pre-push` hook is still my preferred implementation - a nice way to keep the logic isolated to the repo's context.

Answer (score 4):

Set up your pre-push hook to prevent pushing **unless** the file `.testspassed` exists. Example:

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-push <<EOF
#!/bin/sh -e

if ! [ -f .testspassed ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "push aborted because tests were not run or did not all pass"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
EOF
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

Set up your prepare-commit-msg hook to remove `.testspassed` if it exists:

```
cat > .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg <<EOF
#!/bin/sh -e

rm -f .testspassed
exit 0
EOF
```

I'm using `prepare-commit-msg` instead of `pre-commit` because `prepare-commit-msg` runs on merges too. Any time you commit or merge, git will remove the `.testspassed` file, preventing you from pushing.

Tell git to ignore the `.testspassed` file so it doesn't end up in your repo:

```
echo .testspassed >> .gitignore
git commit -m 'add .testspassed to .gitignore' .gitignore
```

Finally, modify your test-run process to create (“touch”) `.testspassed` if all your tests pass. How you do this depends on how you run your tests.

Comment: Very nice. I'm leaving my answer in place for a general-purpose bash-centric demonstration of how to wrap other commands, but this is very much the Right Thing in the context.

Comment: A few notes/caveats, by the way -- the default exit status of bash is that of the most recent command to exit, so the explicit `exit 0` is unnecessary. (If a condition exists that prevents `.testspassed` from being deleted, that probably _should_ be brought to the user's attention loudly!)

Comment: When the return code matters, I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: BTW, being able to put the redirection anywhere in the command is a bashism. To comply with POSIX sh (since you're using `#!/bin/sh`), the `>&2` should go at either the very beginning or the very end. Or you could change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

First: This won't work (not in a technical sense, but in a human-habit sense). See Rob Mayoff's idea instead.

However, to demonstrate an implementation, you could put the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
git() {
  if [[ $1 = push ]]; then
    printf %s "Did you run unit tests locally?"
    read response
    case $response in
      y|Y|yes|YES) command git "$@" ;;
      *)           echo "Aborting" ;;
    esac
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Better, to implement Rob's idea:

```
git() {
  local -a options=( )
  while (( $# )) && [[ $1 = -* ]]; do
    case $1 in
      -C|-c) options+=( "$1" "$2" ); shift; shift ;;
      *)     options+=( "$1" ); shift ;;
    esac
  done
  local base_dir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
  case $1 in
    commit|merge|rebase)
      touch "$base_dir/.untested"
      command git "${options[@]}" "$@"
      ;;
    push)
      if [[ -e "$base_dir/.untested" ]]; then
        echo "Untested commits exist; you must run tests"
      else
        command git "${options[@]}" "$@"
      fi
      ;;
    *) command git "${options[@]}" "$@" ;;
  esac
}

unittest() (
  cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
  make test && rm .untested
)
```

Comment: I know the OP mentions that s/he uses Bash, but why not improve portability and avoid bashisms such as `[[...]]`? Also, you should mention that your wrapper won't work if some Git command-line options are used, such as the `-c` flag.

Comment: @Jobobs, because, for one thing, the best way to make it work with those options would be using a bashism -- arrays -- to store arguments being "eaten". Being in the habit of using `[[ ]]` when in a bash-only context is a Good Thing -- it's significantly less error-prone (no string-splitting, no glob expansion) and more capable (pattern matching, regex operations, etc).

Comment: @Jobobs, ...for instance, if I were using `[ ]` instead of `[[ ]]`, the unquoted use of `$1` would have been a bug.

Comment: Anyhow -- as amended, this fixes stashing options (assuming they don't take arguments, or have their arguments squashed into the same string) using an array, which makes the code very much bash-specific. (Granted, an approach that was willing to encode more knowledge about `git` could recognize options that themselves take arguments, but I'm calling this proof-of-concept).

Comment: @Jubobs, yes, see the caveats in my comment above.

Comment: Actually, looking at current usage, it looks like `-c` and `-C` are the only two special cases, so I've handled them both.